# How to get system date without time-stamp in the data type of Date?

Tags: java, string, date, comparison

i need to compare two dates 
   task.deadline have Date data type but when i get system date it gives me in string how to get system date in Date data type

```
if (!task.deadline.before(systemDate)) {
            // add row to to do tab
            model_1.addRow(row);
        } else {
            // add row to done tab
            model_2.addRow(row);
        }
```

Comment: is that `java` or `c#`? If so please add it as a tag to get better help.

Comment: which language you are using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the `systemDate` to a Date

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date sysDate = sdf.parse(systemDate);`

Now you can use `sysDate` in the comparison.